# Passing a property values in a model from controller to view - Displaying incorrect data

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm passing the properties values from a model in the controller to the view, but one of the property values that I'm displaying on the view has the same data as one of the property, even though the data that's come back from the query shows that it's different.

For example, when I display ID and EmployeeID on the view, both of them has the same data being display. However, the data coming back from the query is different. Everything else is displaying correctly except ID and EmployeeID

The only solution I've found was to create a new list and then add the data to the list and return it.

Controller

```
var ReturnData = db.People.Where(s => s.EmployeeeID == EmployeeID && s.Schedule == Schedule).FirstOrDefault();

return PartialView("PersonPartial", ReturnData);
```

View

```
@model Project.Models.People

@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.ID)
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.EmployeeID)   
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.FirstName)
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.LastName)
```

Model

```
[Table("People")]
public class People{
    public int ID {get;set;}
    public int EmployeeID{get;set;}
    public string FirstName{get;set;}
    public string LastName{get;set;}
    public string Schedule{get;set;}
}
```

Comment: Is the method in the controller inside of a `Post`? Is the `TextBoxFor`'s inside of a `Form`?

Comment: The method is inside of the controller and it's a GET. The TextBoxFor is inside of Ajax.BeginForm, which doesn't matter until the data is POST. Displaying the data shouldn't matter if it's inside of form or not.

Comment: So, correct me if I'm wrong, but your `ReturnData` variable has different data then what renders when you pop the screen? I think you should show us those values and some more code as well, because something doesn't add up there.

Comment: Yes, it has different data then what's being render. Well the only data that's different is ID and EmployeeID. ID has the data of EmployeeID being display, even though in ReturnData, you can see that the data for ID is different. The other solution I came up with was to create a ViewModel and add the Exclusion Model in there and when I query back the data, add it to the VM and display the VM data.

Comment: Are you using EF Core?  I'm wondering if this is a problem where EF is not tracking a primary key.